# To attract members of the channel specified in Telegram and send messages

Tags: python, telethon, pyrogram

how can I attract members of a group or channel in telegram using python and send them a specified message? I couldn't find any resources on this subject, can it be done with pyrogram or telethon?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean send them messages privately from a bot, you can't do that.
Telegram doesn't allow that.
User has to reach us to the bot in order for the bot to send messages.

Although you want to send messages to your bot users, you can use **pymongo** or any other database and store user info (id, name etc). Then by accessing and iterating through the IDs you can send messages.

And you mean sending them messages within the group, you can just create a update filter and add reply to it.

Don't think there's any way of doing this in a channel.